# Extracting Specific Information from file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a file created from a command I run on my system. After the file is created I want to extract only specific information from that file but only it it meets certain criteria.

Here is what my file looks like:

```
client: tc-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
        version: xxxx
        uuid: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
        user-uid: 10000
        user: someuser
        primary-server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        operational-mode: normal
        mac: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
        locked-time: xx:xx:xx
        ipaddr: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        hostname: tc-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
        connection-1: frdp::Green::Test
        connection-0: frdp::Purple::Test
client: tc-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
        version: xxxx
        uuid: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
        user-uid: 10000
        user: someuser
        primary-server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        operational-mode: normal
        mac: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
        locked-time: xx:xx:xx
        ipaddr: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        hostname: tc-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
        connection-0: frdp::Purple::Test
client: tc-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
        version: xxxx
        uuid: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
        user-uid: 10000
        user: someuser
        primary-server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        operational-mode: normal
        mac: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
        locked-time: xx:xx:xx
        ipaddr: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        hostname: tc-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
client: tc-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
        version: xxxx
        uuid: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
        user-uid: 10000
        user: someuser
        primary-server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        operational-mode: normal
        mac: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
        locked-time: xx:xx:xx
        ipaddr: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        hostname: tc-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
        connection-0: frdp::Purple::Test
client: tc-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
        version: xxxx
        uuid: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
        user-uid: 10000
        user: someuser
        primary-server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        operational-mode: normal
        mac: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
        locked-time: xx:xx:xx
        ipaddr: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        hostname: tc-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
client: tc-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
        version: xxxx
        uuid: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
        user-uid: 10000
        user: someuser
        primary-server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        operational-mode: normal
        mac: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
        locked-time: xx:xx:xx
        ipaddr: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        hostname: tc-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
        connection-0: frdp::Purple::Test
client: tc-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
        version: xxxx
        uuid: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
        user-uid: 10000
        user: someuser
        primary-server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        operational-mode: normal
        mac: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
        locked-time: xx:xx:xx
        ipaddr: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        hostname: tc-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
        connection-0: frdp::Green::Test
client: tc-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
        version: xxxx
        uuid: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
        user-uid: 10000
        user: someuser
        primary-server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        operational-mode: normal
        mac: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
        locked-time: xx:xx:xx
        ipaddr: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        hostname: tc-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
        connection-1: frdp::Green::Test
        connection-0: frdp::Purple::Test
```

I want to extract just the client hostnames that just show a connection to Purple and clients with no connections into a new file. I have been able to break out just hostnames or connections using awk but not specific ones without a connection.

EDIT: I have added entries into the file.

Comment: Do you control the generation of this file? That is, is this output of a program you have written? More generally, what command is generating this output? why is this a question about Ubuntu?

Comment: The command that generates the list is proprietary and the system runs on top of Ubuntu. The file is generate by running the command and redirecting the output into a file. This is the format after the command is run.

Comment: Lots of applications run "on top of Ubuntu", but support of those applications is not properly a question *about* Ubuntu. You are asking a general text processing question, and there are several thousand ways to parse that file. You might try asking in the more general unix and linux stackexchange.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want, it is to filter away clients with connections other than 'Purple' (only 'Green' in your example, but possibly other colours).

The following commands use `grep` to remove lines with 'Purple', `tr` to make one line and `sed` to put line breaks before 'client' and finally `grep` to remove remaining lines with 'connection' and to select only the desired piece of information for each client.

The whole information set:

```
< myfile grep -v 'Purple' | tr '\n' ' '| tr -s ' ' ' ' | sed "s/ client/\nclient/g" \
| grep -v 'connection'
```

The hostname and whatever listed behind:

```
< myfile grep -v 'Purple' | tr '\n' ' '| tr -s ' ' ' '  | sed "s/ client/\nclient/g" \
| grep -v 'connection' | grep -o 'hostname: .*'
```

Only hostname, which you wanted according to what I could read:

```
< myfile grep -v 'Purple' | tr '\n' ' '| tr -s ' ' ' '  | sed "s/ client/\nclient/g" \
| grep -v 'connection' | grep -o 'hostname: [^ ]*'
```

---

The other group (that should be filtered out) with hostname and connection other than 'Purple':

```
< myfile grep -v 'Purple' | tr '\n' ' '| tr -s ' ' ' '  | sed "s/ client/\nclient/g" \
| grep 'connection' | grep -o 'hostname: .*'
```